# Is there an sql query to count the number of people in a particular year, knowing the date of birth and the date of death of each person?

Tags: sql, proc-sql

I have a table showing the name, the date of birth and the date of death of people (1900-2000). I need to know the number of people for each year in a certain period of time, for example, in 1940 the population was 2.3 billion, in 1941 2.4 billion, in 1942 2.2 billion and so on until 1950.

I work in SAS Enterprise Guide and maybe the code will look a little different than normal sql. At least I want to see something like this:

~
count of people | year

2.300.000.000   |1940
2.400.000.000   |1941
.....................

```
select
count(name),
from db
where bd<1jan1940 and dd>=1jan1940 and dd=<31dec1940
group by month
```

Comment: `group by year` rather than month

Comment: but using this code, I will only get the number of people who were born before 1940 and died before 1941. I also need to get the number by years for several years

Comment: People who still live have `dd` null? And people who were born before 1900 have `bd` null? And you have a table of person's name, their day of birth and their day of death for all people in the world that lived between 1900 and 2000? That's a lot of data. Where have you got it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you must know the initial population at the end of 1899. Let's say that was 2 billion. Then add births minus deaths for each year. (You must access the table twice in order to do this, once for births and once for deaths.) Use `SUM OVER` to get a running total.

I am not sure which DBMS you are actually using, but this is pretty standard SQL:

```
select yr, 2000000000 + sum(births.cnt - deaths.cnt) over (order by yr)
from
(
  select extract(year from bd) as yr, count(*) as cnt 
  from db
  group by extract(year from bd)
) births
join
(
  select extract(year from dd) as yr, count(*) as cnt 
  from db
  group by extract(year from dd)
) deaths using (yr)
order by yr;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data dob_data;
do i = 1 to 10000;
    num = ceil(rand('UNIFORM',0,10));   
    dob = intnx('day','01JAN1899'd,ceil(rand('UNIFORM',1,36865)));
    select (num);
        when (1)  dod = intnx('day',dob,ceil(rand('UNIFORM',1,36865)));
        otherwise dod = .;
    end;
    output;
end;
format dob dod date9.;
drop num;
run;


data calendar;
    do i=0 to 100;
        year = 1900+i;
        soy = intnx('year','01JAN1900'd,i,'s');
        eoy = intnx('year','01JAN1900'd,i,'e');
        output;
    end;
    format soy eoy date9.;
run;


proc sql;
    create table pop as
    select year,
    sum(case when DOB < soy and coalesce(DOD,'31DEC2200'd) ge soy then 1 else 0 end) as Alive_At_Start,
    sum(case when DOB between soy and eoy then 1 else 0 end) as Born_During,
    sum(case when coalesce(DOD,'31DEC2200'd) between soy and eoy then -1 else 0 end) as Passed,
    sum(case when DOB le eoy and coalesce(DOD,'31DEC2200'd) > eoy then 1 else 0 end) as Alive_At_End
    from dob_data t1, calendar t2
    group by year;
quit;
```